# Find annotation overlaping file in ArcMap 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

I have all my textstring(Annotation) at distance 1.5 feet. I want to find all the annotation which are at a distance of less than 1.5. Also want to find the overlapping file.

Can I make any file like shapefile so that I can zoom to location?

Answer (score 1):

To find overlapping Text, first create Polygons from the text using Feature Envelope to Polygon, then Intersect that layer. To find Text that is closer than 1.5 feet, run Near, inputting the Text polygons and labeled features. You can Select Layer By Attribute where Distance < 1.5.

Comment: Thanks if I  want to create a file(like shape file) of the selection how canI do this?

Comment: When in ArcMap, you can save a selection to a Shapefile, http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Exporting_features